# Umbraco Active Directory create user

Tags: active-directory, umbraco

I've implemented a site using Umbraco 7.1.3 and configured the CMS to use Active Directory for the login. I've followed this official post (https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers/active-directory-membership-provider) and everything works perfectly.

My problem is when I try to create a new user using a user which has successfully logged in using It's AD credentials. Obviously the user I'm using is an Administrator of the CMS.

When I try to create this second user I get an error which points that

> login name already exists

I can't find or understand what is doing Umbraco when it's configured to use AD as `DefaultBackofficeProvider`.

Does it try to create an user in Active Directory?

Comment: Are you using the AD login for the back office (CMS) or the front end?

Comment: Tim, I'm using AD for the backend

Comment: What happens if you try to log into the CMS with a valid AD user that isn't set up in Umbraco?

Comment: They can login successfuly without being created before in the CMS. Is that the way it works? Are the users managed from the AD and not from the CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, the CMS will use the AD as the store of users, but it doesn't create new AD users for you (effectively you can only use the users section in the CMS to assign permission to users who have logged in).

If you wanted the Users section to create AD users for you, you might be able to code something custom yourself?

Comment: Thanks! I'll manage the users from the AD. It'd be great that Umbraco only uses AD for checking users credentials and not allowing all the users to login to backend no matter if they only have Writter privileges.